# AngularJS Web Application

Tags: angularjs, url, web, seo

I have a problem with Web Application, I try to do when a user enter on /#/home to display a text.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-route.js"></script>   
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('cacat', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          template: 'DADA'
        }).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });

      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="cacat">
</body>
```

I tried 127.0.0.1/#/home, 127.0.0.1/home and both doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to enter with 127.0.0.1 or localhost or whatever that uses a host or ip address youll need a web server. such as apache, nginx , etc. are u using a web server?

Comment: You are missing a lot of things..You need to include  `ng-view` and also you need to mention a template path like DADA.html please refer to [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: @Sudakatux ofc I have Apache :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay I havent been home and dont really have apache here to try it out but this works perfectly fine

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-route.js"></script>   
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('cacat', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          template: 'DADA'
        }).
        when('/',{
      template:"<a href='index.html#/home'> Go Home</a>"

        } ).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });

 /*     if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });*/

    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="cacat">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
```

I comment out the history part because i need apache to try that. but you were just missing the ng-view tag basically

Hope it helps